# Google App Engine dev server drops virtualenv's site-packages

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a Google App Engine program in `ROOT-DIR` and a virtualenv with a few libs, including sqlalchemy, in `ROOT-DIR/env`.
I try to run my program using the dev server by doing this (using msys a.k.a. git-bash)

```
$ cd ROOT-DIR 
$ source ./env/Scripts/activate
$ python path-to-gae/dev_appserver.py .
```

The server starts up, but when I browse to `localhost:8080` the server raises an import error on sqlalchemy.
Adding some print statements at the top of the main file, I find that the system path at the point that I'm trying to import sqlalchemy is the following:

```
ROOT-DIR
d:\Google\google_appengine
d:\Google\google_appengine
ROOT-DIR\env\lib
C:\python27\Lib
C:\python27\DLLs
ROOT-DIR\env
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\jinja2-2.6
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\MySQLdb-1.2.4
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\markupsafe-0.15
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\setuptools-0.6c11
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\protorpc-1.0
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\webob-1.1.1
d:\Google\google_appengine\lib\yaml-3.10
```

Obviously, `ROOT-DIR/env/lib/site-packages` isn't there, which explains the import error.

If I start my virtualenv's python shell and do this

```
import sys
for x in sys.path:
    print x
```

I see `ROOT-DIR\env\lib\site-packages`, so it seems that the GAE dev server is *dropping* that path at runtime, or something.

Why is the dev server dropping the site-packages directory?

This is with Python 2.7 on Windows 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use virtualenv to work with local libraries that match the supported 3rd party libs.  For all others you have to install them into the project directory so they get deployed.

Read https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27  paying close attention to "Managing Local Libraries with virtualenv" and then "Adding Third-party Packages to the Application" *especially the second topic*.  There is a difference.

The virtualenv / local libs only exists so that you don't have to install these libraries in your project folder, or in your base python distribution. If you were to install these in your project you would need to remove before deployment. Remember all custom 3rd party libs need to be deployed with your code. The "Local libs" is for google supported libraries only.

Comment: Still don't get it. If the dev server is explicitly dropping the site-packages directory from my virtualenv, then *none* of my virtualenv's libs will be picked up unless I do the `pip install -t lib mylib` thing. This seems inconsistent with the idea that "supported" libs should work in the usual virtualenv way. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yep, the virtualenv / local libs only exists so that you don't have to install these libraries in your project folder, or in your base python distribution. If you where to install these in your project you would need to remove before deployment.  Remember all custom 3rd party libs need to be deployed with your code.  The "Local libs" is for google supported libraries only.

Comment: I still don't understand this. From the section in the linked page titled "Managing Local Libraries with virtualenv", I quote: "With the environment active, you can run dev_appserver.py as usual. It will use the environment's libraries, and not use other libraries you have installed on your computer." If, as I've described, the dev server is dropping site-packages from my virtualenv, then how can the quoted statement be true?

Comment: It is true but only for supported 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Let me try to be explicit: if the dev server drops the virtualenv's site-packages directory from the system path, how is it physically possible for the dev server to load _any_ third party libs, supported or otherwise, from that virtualenv?

Comment: Rather than asking questions have a look at the code. What makes you think it just drops the path completely ?    A quick perusal of  the source - specifically https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py which covers the code performing the importing a libraries and setting up the whitelist you will see a definition of   ALLOWED_SITE_PACKAGE_FILES on line 284 which sets up a list file modules that are allowed to be in the site packages, (be they installed in python or a virtualenv). This is not the complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to read the code. To answer your question "What makes you think it just drops the path completely?", as explicitly shown in the OP, the path to site-packages is not in `sys.path` at run time. I realize what's going on is more complicated than that simple fact might suggest, but it is precisely this complication that I'm trying to understand. FWIW the recommended way to handle 3rd party libs is annoying because the virtualenv can't import them if they're installed into an alternative `lib` directory as suggested. In other words, they *only* work via the dev server.